# Позиционирование background

Tags: css3, html5, background, bootstrap4, background-image

Делаю лендинг на **bootstrap 4** (применяю только сетку). Нужно поставить фоны для блоков. Не могу понять, как правильно их ставить, подключить и спозцонировать, чтобы они были за блоком **container**, то есть растягивались на всю ширину сайта, а не только в пределах контентной части. Заранее спасибо.[image: в красной области должно быть продолжение фона]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть единицы `vw` (viewport width) и `vh` (viewport height). Первая привязана к текущей ширине экрана, вторая - к высоте. В процентах. Поэтому можно задать `background-size: 100vw 100vh;` и покрыть всё. Дополнительно добавить `background-attachment: fixed;` чтобы при скролле вниз, картинка оставалась на месте и никуда не уходила.

Но если у контента есть минимальная ширина - иногда она оказывается больше, чем ширина экрана. Для таких случаев 100vw заменено на указанные пиксели, как у блока-контента.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/3efgprcL/) - растягивайте окно.

```css
*{margin: 0;}

body {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/371589/pexels-photo-371589.jpeg');
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { body {background-size: 600px 100vh;} }

.main {
  width: 60%; min-width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  color: white; font-size: 30px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    Какой-то контент...
  </div>
</body>
```